# Backbone.js basics: creating a view

Tags: backbone.js

I'm just starting to learn backbone.js. I'm following [this tutorial](http://backbonetutorials.com/what-is-a-view/) here at backbonetutorials.com, but for some reason I'm not being able to put it working. Here's what I've got so far ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/eykKL/)):

```
var View = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('.container'),

    initialize: function() {
        this.render();
    },

    render: function() {
        var templ = _.template($('#template').html(), {});
        this.el.html(templ);

    },

    events: {
        "click button": "buttonClick"
    },

    buttonClick: function() {
        alert('clicked!');
    }
});

var view = new View();​
```

What's wrong with the above? I've almost just copy/pasted from the tutorial to the fiddle. Is it related to the backbone/underscore versions being used?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest you not to couple your view with element's selector. You can pass it in the constructor parameter: http://jsfiddle.net/deXUs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
this.$el.html(templ);
```

instead of

```
this.el.html(templ);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eykKL/4/

Comment: `$el` is a cached jquery object of your view element. `el` has no `html()` method, its a jquery method.

Comment: So I'm wrong to assume that `view.el = $('.container');` and, that therefore view.el is a jQuery object?

Comment: Have a look at the source code: https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L1242

Comment: Thanks! That was actually what I was doing before coming back here.

Comment: Exactly what CD says. One thing to note. The `$el` is simply a convenience that wraps the `el` for you. On the other end of things, you might just use plain old `el` if you're using it inside a jQuery function like so: $('.container').html(view.render().el); No need to wrap it again. `this.$el` is also pretty much the same as saying `$(this.el)`

Comment: Thanks. $(this.el) feels more natural. I'm going to stick with it.